# OS X El Capitan different behaviours at start

Tags: macos

I have two MacBook Pro mid 2013, same hardware inside.
In the first one I had the following sequence of OSs.
Mountain Lion (factory) > Mavericks > Yosemite > El Capitan > El Capitan (Clean Install)

And whenever I start the Mac I have this flow
**Apple Logo** > **User login** (my user + guest user) > **Loading** (progress bar) > **OS loaded**

In the second MacBook I had
Mountain Lion (factory) > El Capitan

And this flow at start
**Apple Logo** > **Loading** (progress bar) > **User login** (my user + guest user) > **OS "lazy" loaded** ("lazy" = Status bar is loaded a few seconds after the screen with dock is presented)

Since there is a clearly difference in the behaviour of the two OSs, my question is: why does this happen? Is there a problem with one of the OSs? Which is the correct flow?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It might be that in the first case the boot partition is encrypted with FileVault. You then need to login to be able to read the boot partition.

Comment: Yep, fileVault was turned off. Now the flow is the same.

Answer (score 0):

I have went through similar steps as you with your first MBP and have the same flow as yours. I have watched quite a lot of videos of the new OS's and as far as I know the "flow" should be : Apple Logo -> login -> loading bar -> Desktop.

---

I am not 100% sure but I think I have been given a loading screen right after the Apple Logo but right now I can't think of the reason. Point being: Your first MBP is fine for sure. The loading after the apple logo on your second one might be just some updates? installing in the background. Try using it more intensively and if the loading doesn't stop appearing I guess you would have to do a clean install. Either way I think **you should be good** running both the way they are.

Comment: The fact is that after the login no loading (progress bar) is showed, the Desktop in loaded immediatly with the only exception of the status bar which is presented a few seconds after. I think the system starts loading stuff before the login, don't know why and if it may have consequences.